# How can I change or customize the alert colors bootstrap 4 and Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap gem 4.0.0.beta2.1, Rails 5.1.4 and standard bootstrap alerts (class: "alert alert-info"). They are nice, but don't fit to my styling. I would like to have the white background for example. How can I customize it? Is there any way I can change Bootstrap4 variables?

Comment: Add a custom class instead of alert-info and apply your styling to your custom class..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add custom classes to your alert div. In my case i have added "alert-custom" class instead of alert-* and applied css to it as follows

html:

```
<div class="alert alert-custom  fade in alert-dismissable show" style="margin-top:18px;">
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:20px">×</span>
  </button>    <strong>Success!</strong> This alert box indicates a successful or positive action.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.alert-custom{
  background-color:#6089D5;
  color:#fff;
}
```

For Your Reference: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pradeep0594/ht93o6r5/2/)

Comment: I was looking more for customizing some variables something like:  adding  $jumbotron-bg: blue; to /app/assets/stylesheets/bootstraply.css.scss in bootrstap3 - is it still valid for bootstrap4?

Comment: Not sure. But my kind advice not to customise core files. Instead try to override it

Comment: @MickLasocki Bootstrap 4.5 documentation now enables "Theming" - which provides a means for customizing things like colors.  See documentation here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/theming/

Comment: @pradeepkumar I tend to agree, touch less of the internals of a framework, and risk less.  The trade-off when using bootstrap is that it could require a huge set of customized classes to reap the benefits of the bootstrap class naming convention (e.g. if you are customizing the color for "primary" - then you need to customer "btn-primary," "text-primary," "alert-primary" etc. etc. - which becomes messy very quickly.

Answer (score 12):

In Bootstrap's `_variables.scss`, there are variables related to alert colors:

```
$alert-bg-level:     -10 !default;
$alert-border-level:  -9 !default;
$alert-color-level:    6 !default;
```

I can't find any mention of these in the documentation, but the values appear to adjust the lightness or darkness of the color passed in by whichever class is applied to the alert (e.g. `alert-primary`).

So for example, if you override `$alert-bg-level` with `0`, the background color of `.alert-primary` will be identical to whatever color you've defined as `$primary`, whereas a value of `10` will make it darker or a value of `-10` will make it lighter.

The background and border colors use a scale of `-10` to `10`, while the text color seems to use a scale of `0` to `10`.

Comment: Just what I was looking for.  Thank you

Comment: Bootstrap 4.5 documents the sass variables for theming here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/theming/